# Как расположить один div над другим?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите, как мне сделать так, чтобы левая граница `.logo` была над левой границей меню, а правая граница заголовка — над правой границей меню. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сейчас у этих трех элементов такие стили:

```
.header {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
}

.name {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 700px;
  line-height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: 100px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Почему вы не сделаете одну ширину и для меню и для заголовка? А потом логотип и название выровнять по краям?

Comment: padding: auto - такого свойства нет. Есть padding: [top, right, bottom, left]

Answer (score 1):

Если `.logo` и `.name` у вас находится внутри `.header`, задайте для класса `.header` ширину и отступы (margins), идентичные стилю класса `.menu`.

Смысл такой:

```
.header {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}

.logo { float: left; }

.name { float: right; }

.menu {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: `.header` будет иметь высоту **0** из за того, что его дочерние элементы имеют `float`. Задайте высоту блоку `.header`

Comment: @Yuri, или `clear: both;` :)

Comment: check1st, это да. Только у меня, по какой-то магической причине, он не всегда срабатывает )

Answer (score 0):

Решение с помощью flexbox, которое решает проблемы вертикального центрирования и упрощает задание ститей:

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 5%;;
}

.logo {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    Рейтинг студий маникюра Москвы
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">
      Рейтинг
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      Контакты
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```